# Error in using JPA prepared statement

Tags: jpa, db2

I am new to JPA. I'm trying to execute a prepared statement but I kept getting an error. Can you tell what's wrong? Thank you.

**This is the entity with prepared statement:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TCMSPRUSR", schema="TCMS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.getName", query = "SELECT u.empnam FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserid", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userid = :userid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmpno", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.empno = :empno"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmpnam", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.empnam = :empnam"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword1", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password1 = :password1"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword2", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password2 = :password2"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword3", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password3 = :password3"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword4", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password4 = :password4"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEffdte", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.effdte = :effdte"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPcname", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.pcname = :pcname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAtmptcnt", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.atmptcnt = :atmptcnt"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByDaysexp", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.daysexp = :daysexp"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPwdate", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.pwdate = :pwdate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByStatdesc", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.statdesc = :statdesc"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByStatcode", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.statcode = :statcode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUseflg", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.useflg = :useflg"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByCuser", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.cuser = :cuser"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByCdate", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.cdate = :cdate")})
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private String userid="0";
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMPNO")
    private int empno;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "EMPNAM")
    private String empnam;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD1")
    private String password1;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD2")
    private String password2;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD3")
    private String password3;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD4")
    private String password4;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EFFDTE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date effdte;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PCNAME")
    private String pcname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ATMPTCNT")
    private short atmptcnt;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DAYSEXP")
    private short daysexp;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PWDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date pwdate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STATDESC")
    private String statdesc;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "STATCODE")
    private long statcode;
    @Column(name = "USEFLG")
    private Short useflg;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CUSER")
    private String cuser;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date cdate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORGACODE", referencedColumnName = "ORGACODE")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Organization orgacode;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID", referencedColumnName = "ROLEID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Role roleid;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userid")
    private Collection<AuditTrail> auditTrailCollection;
```

**This is the class that uses the prepared statement:**

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TCMS-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> uList = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u").getResultList();
        return uList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getName() {
        List<User> uList = em.createQuery("SELECT u.empnam FROM User u").getResultList();
        return uList;
    }
}
```

The getName() method executed with no problem, but the findAll() method has error.

**HERE IS THE STACK TRACE**

```
[5/3/16 9:32:19:456 CST] 00000244 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "findAll" on bean "BeanId(TCMS#TCMSEJB.jar#UserFacade, null)". Exception data: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1686911 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=ASG2.TCMSPRUSR, DRIVER=4.13.127 {prepstmnt 1878102677 SELECT t0.USERID, t0.ATMPTCNT, t0.CDATE, t0.CUSER, t0.DAYSEXP, t0.EFFDTE, t0.EMPNAM, t0.EMPNO, t1.ORGACODE, t1.CDATE, t1.CUSER, t1.ORGAABBR, t1.ORGADESC, t1.STATUS, t0.PASSWORD, t0.PASSWORD1, t0.PASSWORD2, t0.PASSWORD3, t0.PASSWORD4, t0.PCNAME, t0.PWDATE, t2.ROLEID, t2.ACCTIND, t2.CDATE, t2.CUSER, t2.ROLEDESC, t2.UNITCAT, t0.STATCODE, t0.STATDESC, t0.USEFLG FROM TCMSPRUSR t0 INNER JOIN CFASFA0740 t1 ON t0.ORGACODE = t1.ORGACODE INNER JOIN TCMSPRROL t2 ON t0.ROLEID = t2.ROLEID  optimize for 1 row} [code=-204, state=42704]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLNQ1F7, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0]
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=ASG2.TCMSPRUSR, DRIVER=4.13.127
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;ASG2.TCMSPRUSR, DRIVER=4.13.127
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;ASG2.TCMSPRUSR, DRIVER=4.13.127
FailedObject: SELECT u FROM User u [java.lang.String]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4996)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4956)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:571)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:70)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.handleCheckedException(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:40)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1258)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1014)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:870)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:330)
    at ph.gov.bsp.tcms.core.UserFacade.findAll(UserFacade.java:29)
    at ph.gov.bsp.tcms.core.EJSLocalNSLUserFacade_55a49658.findAll(EJSLocalNSLUserFacade_55a49658.java)
    at ph.gov.bsp.tcms.test.Test.print(Test.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:83)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:404)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:103)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:995)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:278)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1307)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:733)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=ASG2.TCMSPRUSR, DRIVER=4.13.127 {prepstmnt 1878102677 SELECT t0.USERID, t0.ATMPTCNT, t0.CDATE, t0.CUSER, t0.DAYSEXP, t0.EFFDTE, t0.EMPNAM, t0.EMPNO, t1.ORGACODE, t1.CDATE, t1.CUSER, t1.ORGAABBR, t1.ORGADESC, t1.STATUS, t0.PASSWORD, t0.PASSWORD1, t0.PASSWORD2, t0.PASSWORD3, t0.PASSWORD4, t0.PCNAME, t0.PWDATE, t2.ROLEID, t2.ACCTIND, t2.CDATE, t2.CUSER, t2.ROLEDESC, t2.UNITCAT, t0.STATCODE, t0.STATDESC, t0.USEFLG FROM TCMSPRUSR t0 INNER JOIN CFASFA0740 t1 ON t0.ORGACODE = t1.ORGACODE INNER JOIN TCMSPRROL t2 ON t0.ROLEID = t2.ROLEID  optimize for 1 row} [code=-204, state=42704]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1118)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1801)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:258)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.executeQuery(SelectImpl.java:499)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:391)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:427)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:220)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:34)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Is the table under the same user as you are logged in with?

Comment: stored procedure or prepared statement? And did you search what the error codes mean? This error is not jsf related, did you try in a plain java class/unit test? Same error?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Yes, it is.

Comment: Could you show the whole entity. It is also joining CFASFA0740 and TCMSPRROL, are those under the same user as well?

Comment: @Kukeltje My bad, it is prepared statement. Btw, I added schema to the table annotation and it executed this query _"SELECT u.empnam FROM User u"_ with no problem but when I tried executing _"SELECT u FROM User u"_ to get all the columns, the same error shows. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I updated the entity above. Thanks.

Comment: Did SELECT u.empnam... not work before adding schema? Then add shema to the other entities as well. Otherwise delete properties until second query works. I'd guess its the last 3 properties

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Yes. I did put the schema on the 3 entities and it works. Thanks a lot. :)